# Javascript map function to create multiple objects

Tags: javascript

I need some dummy data that I can use. I usually, manually create my data in a variable like...

```
const jsonData = [
  {
    name: 'random',
    age: '0',
  }
];
```

I'm trying to create a function that gives me back an array with a list of objects in (like the above) the amount of objects in the array is based on the value I give it.

I came to the conclusion using the `map` function would be best, like so:

```
const myMap = new Map();

myMap.forEach((q, n) => {

});
```

I'm still learning. Honestly now sure how I'd go about creating this.

Comment: A JavaScript object is not the same as JSON. [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Look for "dummy" APIs, that serve lists in JSON. For example, [JSONPlaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simple loop:

```
function genData(n) {
  var results = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    results.push({name: 'random', age: 0});
  }
  return results;
}
```

If you want to randomize the property values, look into [`Math.random`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random).

---

Here is a simple example that picks a random value from provided lists:

```js
function genData(n, values) {
  var results = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var obj = {};
    for (var prop in values) {
      obj[prop] = values[prop][Math.floor(Math.random() * values[prop].length)];
      results.push(obj);
    }
  }
  return results;
}

console.log(genData(3, {name: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], age: [0, 10, 20, 30, 40]}));
```